# Angular $resource success callback response value?

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise, ngresource

I am trying to use the $resource for REST API interaction with following code:

Inside Factory:

```
api.user = $resource(api.baseUrl + '/admin/login', {}, {
          login: {method:'POST'}
        });
```

Controller One:

```
        vm.user.$login().$promise.then(function(successResult) {
          console.log(successResult);
        }, function(errorResult) {
          console.log(errorResult);
          if(errorResult.status === 404) {
          }
        });
```

I get the error : "TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined" as the $promise is undefined for the resource object.

> Question 1: I read on multiple questions that one can use the $promise
>   property to write the callbacks. What am I doing wrong here that the
>   $promise property is coming as undefined for login method on user object.

Controller Two:

```
vm.user.$login(function(successResult) {
          console.log(successResult);
        }, function(errorResult) {
          console.log(errorResult);
          if(errorResult.status === 404) {
          }
        });
```

This properly processes the success/error handling, however on the successResult object, there are two additional properties of $promise:undefined, $resolved: true, while I was assuming successResponse should be the actual plain object returned by the server, but it looks like an instance of $resource.

> Q2: Is there a way to capture the plain object returned by the server
>   while using the $resource, not having $resource properties?

Any help to resolve the confusion is appreciated.

Comment: as per angular docs, the $resource returns a object while in ControllerOne you trying to get a `promise`

Comment: $resource returned an object which I assigned to api.user and then I am calling the $login method on that, which as per my understanding(not correct may be) should return a resource object, and a valid $promise property, while it is comeing as undefined. I hope this clarifies it a bit.

Comment: @user1242321, can you take a look in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call your `factory` method this way: `vm.user.login().$promise.then(function(data) {...`

Also you need to use `return`, as the following: `return $resource(api.baseUrl + '/admin/login', {}, {...`

I made a snippet, check it:

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";
  angular.module('app', ['ngResource'])
    .controller('mainCtrl', function(userFactory) {
      var vm = this;

      vm.data = {};
      vm.login = function() {
        userFactory.login().$promise.then(function(data) {
          vm.data = data.status;
        }, function(data) {
          console.log(data);
        });
      }
    })

  .factory('userFactory', function($http, $resource) {
    return $resource('http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON?', {}, {
      login: {
        method: 'POST'
      }
    });
  })
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl as main">
  Response: <pre ng-bind="main.data | json"></pre>
  <hr>
  <button type="button" ng-click="main.login()">Login</button>
</body>

</html>
```